# C++ - How does the >> operator work?

Tags: c++

I have a question regarding the `>>` operator.
I wrote a program to count number of words in a binary file.
My question is about the while loop, shouldn't the `>>` read the space, go into the loop, increment c, but just not put anything into w ?
It gives me an output of 4, but counting the spaces shouldn't it be 10?
 Any help is appreciated. My code is below:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<fstream.h>
ofstream a;
ifstream b;
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    char w[20];
    a.open("newf.txt",ios::binary);
    a<<"This  is an   example\n";
    a.close();
    b.open("newf.txt");
    int c=0;
    while(b>>w)
    { 
        c++ ;
    }
    cout<<c;
    b.close();
    getch();  
}
```

Comment: Most overloads of `operator>>` (including the one you are calling) [skip all leading whitespace first thing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/FormattedInputFunction).

Comment: I'm not sure if you're aware of this, but you're using deprecated headers.  `<iostream>` should be used in place of `<iostream.h>`, for example.

Comment: See also: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws

Comment: If you are reading a binary file you should be using the `read` memeber function.

Comment: Also, if you're interested, you can find documentation on istream's operator>> [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.0/classstd_1_1basic__istream.html)

Comment: Note your use of `ios::binary` is inconsistent. You're opening a file and writing ascii text to it - so you shouldn't specify `ios::binary`. When you open the file again for reading you don't specify `ios::binary`, so you're acknowledging you're reading a text file.

Comment: *count number of words in a binary file* - if you mean words in the sense of ascii text separated by whitespace, this statement doesn't make sense. Binary files are different to ascii files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the *operator>>* in *ifstream* ignores the whitespaces. If you want the whitespaces to be included, you have to use the std::noskipws manipulator flag as shown in the official documentation [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/noskipws/).

Answer (score 1):

First off, you're extracting into `char w[20]` **don't do this**. If a sting longer than 20 character is extracted bad things will happen. Instead use `string w`.

[`string::operator>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) is what is called by `b >> w` which will:

> Behaves as a FormattedInputFunction. After constructing and checking the sentry object, which may skip leading whitespace, first clears `str` with `str.erase()`, then reads characters from `is` and appends them to `str` as if by `str.append(1, c)`, until one of the following conditions becomes true:
>
> - N characters are read, where N is `is.width()` if `is.width() > 0`, otherwise N is `str.max_size()`
> - the end-of-file condition occurs in the stream `is`
> - `std::isspace(c,is.getloc())` is true for the next character `c` in `is` (this whitespace character remains in the input stream).
>
> If no characters are extracted then `std::ios::failbit` is set on `is`, which may throw `std::ios_base::failure`.
>
> Finally, calls `os.width(0)` to cancel the effects of `std::setw`, if any.